# Get part of parent node's content via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

How i can get parent object of this anchor via javaScript ?

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 
text of the printing and typesetting
<a href="http://somplace.com/index.php?content=
{{in this place i want to retrieve 20 character of 
the parent p}}"></a> industry.
</p>
```

Comment: Why so low rate of acceptance??

Comment: I think this time you have got the answer. So please mark the answer as accepted..simple. :D

Comment: yeah of course , im awaiting for time 20 sec reminded to a check the accept check mark ! ;) thanks bro ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.parentNode.innerHTML.substring(0, 20)`:

```
<a onclick="alert(this.parentNode.innerHTML.substring(0, 20)" ..............
```

Here:

- `this` refers to current link
- `parentNode` refers to parent of link eg paragraph in this case
- `innerHTML` to read parent's html
- `substring` used to get chars from 0 to 20 in this case.

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/umeqop/2)

Comment: @bizzare: Updated, please check.

Comment: `innerText` may not be cross-browser.

Comment: yes i have an error in mozila ` this.parentNode.innerText is undefined `

Comment: use InnerHTML for cross browser support.

Comment: @Pranav: Yeah `innerText` isn't cross-browser solution, having worked on facebook development where you can do `setText` or innerText has made this habit, trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have a reference to the anchor tag in a variable named `anchorElement`, you can get the parent like this:

```
var anchorParent = anchorElement.parentNode;
```

Or, if you're trying to get a reference to the anchor, you can give it an id and do it like this to actually get the text and put it into the href:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 
text of the printing and typesetting
<a id="myAnchor" href="http://somplace.com/index.php?content=
{{in this place i want to retrieve 20 character of 
the parent p}}"></a> industry.
</p>

var elem = document.getElementById("myAnchor");  // get anchor object
var parent = elem.parentNode;                // get parent
var text = parent.innerHTML.substr(0,20);    // get first 20 chars of text
elem.href = "http://somplace.com/index.php?content=" + text;
```